# Define a three-dimensional array of ints in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, integer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSa1X.png) << Question.
Hello, I'm a little confused. I can't access the 3rd data. I can't get the calculations right. Actually, I'm not entirely sure if I conveyed the problem asked in the question to the code correctly. Can anyone help with the problem? Thank you.

`

```
package arraysProgram;

public class P05 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String[ ] bank = {"INFO", "ACCOUNT", "MONEY"};
        int cst, acc, cash, total = 0;

        int[][][] opers = {
                { {100, -50, 25}, {150,-300}, {300,-90,100} },
                { {90, -60, 250}, {300,20,-100} },
                { {20, 50}, {300}, {20,-20,40}, {100,-200} }
        };

        for(cst = 1; cst<3;)

        {
            for(int i = 2; i < 3; i++)
            {
                System.out.println("BANK " +bank[i]+ ": ");
                for(acc = 0; acc < 3; acc++)
                {
                    System.out.println("Customer Account" +(acc + 1) + (" : "));
                    for(cash = 0; cash < 3; cash++)
                    {
                        System.out.print(opers[cst][acc][cash]+ " ");

                        total += opers[cst][acc][cash];

                    }
                    System.out.println("\nTotal Money: " +total);

                    total = 0;
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Your array is not 3 x 3 x 3, it is a ragged array.  For example, `opers[0][1]` has only 2 elements,, `opers[2]` has 4. Therefore, fixed literal upper bounds in the nested for-loops are wrong.  And why you've got 4 nested loops for a 3-D array is unclear.

Comment: @accessviolation If you have time, can you write the code you mentioned, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: Java doesn't have true multidimensional arrays. It allows array elements to be arrays. So, you can have an array of arrays. You can have an array of arrays of arrays. You can have an array of arrays of arrays of arrays. You can have ...

Comment: is `for(cst = 1; cst<3;)` actually what you meant?  I don't see where the value of `cst` is changed within the for loop.

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer Frankly, I am not at the level to perceive what you are saying. I started the software 1 month ago. Right now, I can't detect it without seeing the code and comparing it with my own code.

Comment: Your code has the upper bounds of the arrays "hard coded" (literal) in the for loops. Each subarray has its own length. You need to use `opers.length`, `opers[x].length`, `opers[x][y].length`. Use your own variables instead of `x` and `y`.

Comment: @AlienWare - it looks like Gilbert Le Blanc has already written the code you're asking for.  No need for me to do so, now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your output is supposed to look like.  Here's what I produced.

```
Customer 1; account 1; total balance 75
Customer 1; account 2; total balance -150
Customer 1; account 3; total balance 310
Customer 2; account 1; total balance 280
Customer 2; account 2; total balance 220
Customer 3; account 1; total balance 70
Customer 3; account 2; total balance 300
Customer 3; account 3; total balance 40
Customer 3; account 4; total balance -100
```

The object of this exercise is to process a three-dimensional `int` array.  This requires three `for` loops.

I spelled out the words customer, account, and change.  Change meaning either a deposit or a withdrawal.

In Java `for` loops are zero-based.  They go from zero to one less than the length of the array.  I added one to the customer number and account number to make them one-based in the output.

I used the lengths of the `int` array in the `for` loops, rather than hard-coding any limits.  This allows you to change the values in the `opers` array without having to make any code changes.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
public class P05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][][] opers = {
                { { 100, -50, 25 }, { 150, -300 }, { 300, -90, 100 } },
                { { 90, -60, 250 }, { 300, 20, -100 } },
                { { 20, 50 }, { 300 }, { 20, -20, 40 }, { 100, -200 } } };
        
        for (int customer = 0; customer < opers.length; customer++) {
            for (int account = 0; account < opers[customer].length; account++ ) {
                int total = 0;
                for (int change = 0; change < opers[customer][account].length; change++) {
                    total += opers[customer][account][change];
                }
                System.out.println("Customer " + (customer + 1) + "; account " +
                        (account + 1) + "; total balance " + total);
            }
        }
    }

}
```